# "if she had" vs "had she"

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, syntactic-analysis

I read the following sentence in a book. I am confused about the sentence structure.

"She thought she would have survived her first term **had she** kept good relations with the army though"

Here "had she" confuses me. Can anyone kindly explain the sentence structure and the use of "had she"?

Can i write it like "**if she had** instead of **had she**"?

For example

"She thought she would have survived her first term **if she had** kept good relations with the army though"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can. It's a conditional construction where instead of having the form of a PP with _if_ as head and a content clause as complement, the protasis takes the form of an ungoverned content clause with subject-auxiliary inversion.  As you say, it is the equivalent of "if she had ... ."

Comment: For native English speaking people or English experts my question might sound duplicate and marking it duplicate doesn't help people with poor English skill, like me. We need exact answer to our exact question. If you are too lazy to explain it properly then please don't even bother to read it and mark it duplicate to earn points.